# Change from paid to free play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have a paid app on the store and I want to know if it is possible to change the price at a later date i.e increase or decrease the price as well as make it free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to make a paid app free. However, it is NOT possible to make a free app paid.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the price and make it free. But once it's free you can't turn into a paid app again unless you reupload under a different id.